# Aggregation in Django viewset - Django Rest Framework:

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, annotations, aggregate-functions, django-filter

I have a table with the following attributes:

```py
created_at = TimestampField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now_update=False, editable=False)  
updated_at = TimestampField(null=True,auto_now_update=True, editable=False)
```

And one service is running there, first comes into the system and we capture **`created_at`** timestamp.

And after some time on service completion, the script updates the table attributes and we capture **`updated_at`** timestamp.

So now I want to find the AVERAGE of the service deployment time i.e. addition of **(`updated_at-created_at`)** divide by total services or we can say total rows in the table.

So that query needs to be implemented in **Django ORM** and have to serialize to the endpoint.

So that data can be fetched in Front-End.

Could you guys help me out here that would be highly appreciable?

Comment: we can use queryset = Server.objects.filter().aggregate(avg_time=Avg(F('updated_at')-F('created_at')))  but i have to serialize the queryset.

Answer (score 1):

I just came to these solutions.

```py
queryset1 = Model.objects.aggregate(y=(Max(F('updated_at')-F('created_at'),output_field=FloatField()))/60000000) # /60000000  to convert microsecond to minutes
```

And:

```py
queryset = Model.objects.filter().values('attr1','attr2')\
               .annotate(min_time=Min(F('updated_at')- 
                F('created_at')),max_time=Max(F('updated_at')- 
                F('created_at')),avg_time=Avg(F('updated_at')- 
                F('created_at'))).order_by('attr1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Update 1:
`Model.objects.annotate(avg_serv_dep=F('modified') - F('created')).aggregate(Avg('avg_serv_dep'))`

---

You can try  `Model.objects.annotate(avg_serv_dep=Avg(F('updated_at') - F('created_at')))`

Comment: I have already implemented that one... it is giving only the time difference in microseconds... the Avg is missing

Comment: or even if I am doing Min, Max as well its is giving the same result...

Comment: You can try `Model.objects.annotate(avg_serv_dep=F('modified') - F('created')).aggregate(Avg('avg_serv_dep'))`